# How do I make my navbar responsive to a tablet?

Tags: html, css, navbar, nav

So, I've started work on a navbar and it's kinda my first time doing this since it's a school project. On PC, my navbar look pretty good, the problem is with how the navbar looks on a tablet. Normally, this wouldn't be a problem, but my school is mostly tablet-centric, so I wanna make it iPad-friendly.

***HTML***

```
<html>
<head>

    <title>Project Layout - Original</title>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="main.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="homecontent.css" type="text/css" />

<style>

</style>

</head>
<body>



<header>

    <div id="container">

    <nav id="nav">

        <ul>
            <img src="finesselogotag.png" id="titleimage"> </img>
            <li><a class="active" href="placeholder.html">Home</a></li>
            <li><a class="nav" href="placeholder.html">Products</a></li>
            <li><a class="nav" href="placeholder.html">Order now</a></li>
            <li><a class="nav" href="placeholder.html">Games</a></li>
            <li><a class="nav" href="placeholder.html">About us</a></li>
            <li><a class="nav" href="placeholder.html">Presentation</a></li>
        </ul>
    </nav>

    </div>

</header>



<div>
    <p>Test text</p>
</div>


<footer>

    <p class="copyright">&copy;Copyright by DLSZ</p>
</footer>

</div>

</body>
</html>
```

***CSS***

```
    /*to remove default margins*/

* {
margin: 0;
list-style-type: none;
background-color: #e0dbd1
}
/*to remove default margins*/

header, nav, section, article, footer {
  display: block;
}

/*Css for the whole div*/
#container {
    list-style: none;
    font-weight: bold;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
    background-color: #1f242e;
    height:49.5px;
    float: left;
}

.logo {
height: 100px;
width: 200px;
float: left;
}


/*CSS for the whole div*/

/*Menu Bar*/

#nav {
float:left;
height: 50px;
text-align: center;
}

#nav ul {
float: left;
margin: 0px;
padding: 0px;
overflow: visible;
}

#nav li {
float: left;
display: block;
height: 19.5px;

}

#nav a {
float: left;
text-decoration: none;
color: #e0dbd1;
font-family: verdana;
}

#nav li a {
    float: left;
        display: block;
        padding: 15px;
        background-color: #1f242e;
        text-align: center;
        font-style: verdana;

}

#titlenav {
float: left;
background-color: #1f242e;
display: block;
font-family: SFAtarian;
padding: 15px;
font-size: 40px;
height: 19.5px;
color: #e0dbd1;
position: absolute;
top: -1.5%;
right: 0%;
}

#titleimage {
position: absolute;
top: -1.95%;
right: 0%;
float: left;
width: 150px;
height: 79.5px;
}

/*Menu Bar*/


section {
height: auto;
width: 1000px;
}

footer {
text-align:center;
height: 40px;
}

footer ul li{
    display: inline-block;
    }

footer ul li a {
    color: 000000;
}

.content {
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 2px;
    margin-left: 50px;
    margin-bottom: 15px;
    margin-top: 25px;
    border: 2px solid black;
    width: 900px;
}

.left {
    float: left;
    margin-right: 5px;
}

.right {
    float: right;
    margin-left: 5px;
}

/*FONTS*/

@font-face {
    font-family: SFAtarian;
    src: url(SFAtarian.ttf);
}
/*END OF FONT LIST*/
```

Here's what it looks like normally: 
[image: Website on PC]

And here's what it looks like on an iPad:
[image: Website on iPad]

*Like I said, I'm kind of new to this kinda thing. Any advice on how to do this would be greatly appreciated, thanks!*

Comment: reference [here](https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_navbar.asp)

Answer (score 0):

```
<head> 
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
</head>
```

use this tag in  section,it will work.
use of viewport : The viewport varies with the device, and will be smaller on a mobile phone than on a computer screen.

Answer (score 0):

Try any of these..
Bootstrap navigation:
https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_navbar.asp

W3.css navigation:
https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/w3css_navigation.asp

Answer (score 0):

```
Check this please, here is the responsive view for your code
```

https://codepen.io/atulraj89/pen/QJVPJv

Comment: hey, it fixed it! is there any way to remove the borders though?

Comment: Yes, But please be specific which border you want to remove, and pls if this answer helped you, upvote this. Will help you as much as possible, Provide the details pls.

Comment: well, the borders in each option. there's a tiny bit of space that I'm not able to remove which only appears in mobile, like you see in the screenshot above. I've upvoted it, but I don't have high enough of a reputation for the score to show.

Comment: In my pen code I am not able to see any space or border kind of thing, this kind of space usually showed up due to display: inline-block; If you are using display inline-block somewhere, get rid off that and then tell me, use float left instead,, and pls remove height from li as well. that's bad approach

Answer (score 0):

```js
$('.hamberger').click(function() {
  $('.hamberger-nav-bar').toggleClass('active-left');
});
```

```css
    /*to remove default margins*/

* {
  margin: 0;
  list-style-type: none;
}

/*to remove default margins*/

header, nav, section, article, footer {
  display: block;
}

/*Css for the whole div*/

#container {
  list-style: none;
  font-weight: bold;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: #1f242e;
  height:49.5px;
  float: left;
}
.logo {
  height: 100px;
  width: 200px;
  float: left;
}


/*CSS for the whole div*/

/*Menu Bar*/

#nav {
  position: relative;
  float:left;
  height: 50px;
  text-align: center;
  margin-top: 50px;
}
#nav ul {
  float: left;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  overflow: visible;
}
#nav li {
  float: left;
  display: block;
  height: 19.5px;
}
#nav a {
  float: left;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #e0dbd1;
  font-family: verdana;
}
#nav li a {
  float: left;
  display: block;
  padding: 15px;
  background-color: #1f242e;
  text-align: center;
  font-style: verdana;
}

#titlenav {
  float: left;
  background-color: #1f242e;
  display: block;
  font-family: SFAtarian;
  padding: 15px;
  font-size: 40px;
  height: 19.5px;
  color: #e0dbd1;
  position: absolute;
  top: -1.5%;
  right: 0%;
}

#titleimage {
  position: absolute;
  top: -1.95%;
  right: 0;
  float: left;
  width: 150px;
  height: 79.5px;
}

/*Menu Bar*/


section {
  height: auto;
  width: 1000px;
}

footer {
  text-align:center;
  height: 40px;
}

footer ul li{
  display: inline-block;
    }

footer ul li a {
  color: 000000;
}

.content {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 2px;
  margin-left: 50px;
  margin-bottom: 15px;
  margin-top: 25px;
  border: 2px solid black;
  width: 900px;
}

.left {
  float: left;
  margin-right: 5px;
}

.right {
  float: right;
  margin-left: 5px;
}
.hamberger {
  display: none;
}

/*FONTS*/

@font-face {
  font-family: SFAtarian;
  src: url(SFAtarian.ttf);
}

/*END OF FONT LIST*/

/* HAMBERGER CSS */

.hamberger {
  position: absolute;
  top: 30px;
  right: 15px;
  z-index: 999999;
  padding: 10px 35px 16px 0;
  cursor: pointer
}

.hamberger span,
.hamberger span:before,
.hamberger span:after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  display: block;
  width: 35px;
  height: 3px;
  border-radius: 1px;
  border-color:#ffffff;
  background: #ffffff;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.hamberger span:before {
  top: -10px;
}

.hamberger span:after {
  bottom: -10px;
}

.hamberger span,
.hamberger span:before,
.hamberger span:after {
  transition: all 300ms ease-in-out;
}

.hamberger.active span {
  background-color: transparent
}

.hamberger.active span:before,
.hamberger.active span:after {
  top: 0;
}

.hamberger.active span:before {
  transform: rotate(45deg);
}

.hamberger.active span:after {
  top: 10px;
  transform: translatey(-10px)   rotate(-45deg);
}

/* MEDIA QUERY */

@media (max-width: 991px){
  .hamberger-nav-bar {
    position: fixed;
    left: -300px;
    width: 300px;
    transition: all 0.5s;
  }
  .hamberger-nav-bar.active-left {
    left: 0;
    position: relative;
  }
  .hamberger-nav-bar.active-left:after {
    position: fixed;
    content: "";
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
    z-index: -1;
  }

  #nav {
    float: none;
    height: auto;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 99;
  }
  #nav ul {
    width: 100%;
    float: none;
  }
  #nav li {
    float: none;
    height: auto;
    width: 100%;
  }
  #nav li a {
    float: none;
  }
  #titleimage {
   top: 0;
  }
  .hamberger {
    float: left;
    margin: 17px 0 0 10px;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 20px;
    display: block;
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Project Layout - Original</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="main.css" />
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="homecontent.css" type="text/css" />
</head>
<body>
<header>
    <div id="container">
      <div class="hamberger">
        <span></span>
      </div>
    <nav id="nav" class="hamberger-nav-bar">
        <ul>
            <li><a class="active" href="placeholder.html">Home</a></li>
            <li><a class="nav" href="placeholder.html">Products</a></li>
            <li><a class="nav" href="placeholder.html">Order now</a></li>
            <li><a class="nav" href="placeholder.html">Games</a></li>
            <li><a class="nav" href="placeholder.html">About us</a></li>
            <li><a class="nav" href="placeholder.html">Presentation</a></li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
      <img src="finesselogotag.png" id="titleimage">
    </div>
</header>
<div>
    <p>Test text</p>
</div>
<footer>
    <p class="copyright">&copy;Copyright by DLSZ</p>
</footer>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Sea the above code.